# Modifying a tkinter canvas from a separate class

Tags: python, canvas, python-3.x, tkinter

What I want to do is create a class (Display) where I can modify the Canvas from any other class.

```
from tkinter import *

#--------# Main #--------#

class Main():
    def Setup(self):
        Display('makeCanvas')
        prun('Setup')

#--------# Display #--------#

class Display(object):
    def __init__(self, cmd):        
        win = Tk()
        win.geometry('500x500')
        self.winCanvas = Canvas(master=win)

        if(cmd == 'makeCanvas'):
            self.winCanvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
        elif(cmd == 'startLoop'):
            mainloop()
        elif(cmd == 'getCanvas'):
            self.sendCanvas()
        else:
            print('Failed')

        self.winCanvas.pack()
    def sendCanvas(self):
        return self.winCanvas

#--------# ConsolePrint #--------#

class ConsolePrint(Display, object):

    def __init__(self, text_given):
        self.tx_g = text_given
        self.totalText = ''
        self.canvas = Display('getCanvas')

 ---->  self.textFeild = self.canvas.create_text()

    def Console(self):
        print("Console")
        self.totalText += (self.tx_g + '\n')
        self.textFeild.append(text=('Console: ' + self.totalText))
        self.textFeild.pack()

class prun(object):
    def __init__(self, text_given):
        print("Printing")
        printer = ConsolePrint(str('*Running: ' + str(text_given) + '*'))
        print("Now the Console")
        printer.Console()

Main().Setup()
```

Its this line of code that isn't working:
self.textFeild = self.canvas.create_text()

The error that comes up is:
AttributeError: 'Display' object has no attribute 'create_text'

I know that I am calling for a function called 'create_text' in Display, yet I don't know how to call the Canvas method in tkinter without inheriting it. I've tried to inherit Canvas in Display, and the error I get is:
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases object, Canvas

All help is appreciated.

Comment: hey, you've spelt field wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access object attributes, in this case, you could just say

```
class ConsolePrint(...):
    def __init__(...):
         ...
         self.textField = self.canvas.winCanvas.create_text(0, 0, text="Whatever")
```

Another change I did above is that you haven't specified any parameters for `create_text`. You will get other errors, though, but that's not the question here.

But basically, you should rethink your script structure. It's unnecessary to create the `Main` and `prun` class and passing commands via strings are really not a good decision. Capsuling code is good, but you're overdoing a bit ;)